# Pandas Unstack Data and Write to CSV

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, pandas

This question has problem been asked a thousand times. But I can't find the said question nor link so anyone who knows this should kindly help me.

I have a DB which I query for data.
Upon getting the data I load it into a pandas. what I need is an efficient way of stacking/unstacking the data

E.g

```
Data:
user_id   data_type      data_value
  2        gender          male
  3        age              32
  2        work_experience  None
  5        work_experience  Engineer
```

How do I rearrange this data such that I get

```
New Data:
user_id gender age work_experience
  2      male   ''    None 
  3      ''     32     ''
  5      ''     ''     Engineer
```

- Mind you the data_type has over 30 distinct values
- Also upon getting the data in this format I need to write to csv  ... This part I think is easy. But I'd love the help with that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.pivot_table`

```
In [644]: df
Out[644]:
   user_id        data_type data_value
0        2           gender       male
1        3              age         32
2        2  work_experience       None
3        5  work_experience   Engineer

In [645]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='user_id',
   .....:                values='data_value', columns='data_type',
   .....:                aggfunc='sum')
Out[645]:
data_type  age gender work_experience
user_id
2          NaN   male            None
3           32    NaN             NaN
5          NaN    NaN        Engineer
```

use `pivot_result.to_csv('file.csv')` to store the result in csv.